# Installing on a computer with USB 3.0 hardware

Tags: installation, drivers, usb

I'm installing Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit version on an HP Envy 15. I get the same problem these people have here:

[Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system-error-when-installing)

but the question was never resolved. I spent so long researching and got so frustrated that I took my computer down to a shop and asked them to install it for me. It took them a while but they managed to get it installed. The reason for this error they had said was because Ubuntu didn't have the USB 3.0 drivers it needed to install properly.

I'm reinstalling Ubuntu yet again and I've run into the same issue so my question is: does anyone know.. a) Where to get these USB 3.0 drivers? b) How to get them installed when installing the Ubuntu OS?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Ubuntu supports USB3.0 already, maybe it's an error with the installer? Perhaps trying to install it via the alternate method might yield better results: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/alternative-download

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give the alternate method a shot. However, I just tried the same installation on another computer and it worked just fine. Again, they told me that they install the USB 3.0 drivers and it worked, so I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: I've succesfully installed Kubuntu 10.10 64-bits on a notebook with 1 USB 3.0 port using the alternative CD. There is a bug in 10.10 that [prevents from suspending](http://askubuntu.com/q/12139/6969), but it can be fixed.

Comment: No dice with the alternative CD. It says it can't detect a CD-ROM drive... but there isn't one in my computer anyways, I'm using a USB to boot. My guess it's just a different way of saying the same error? Thoughts?

Comment: Matt, I'm wondering if you might have better luck using a 10.04 install USB, then upgrade  to 10.10? Just a thought. Reason I'm saying that is because I've had issues with installing 10.10 before, and installing 10.04 then updating from there does the trick.

Comment: I actually tried 10.04 because I thought that was the issue and it didn't work either. Like I said, when I originally went to the shop they said that they installed the usb 3.0 drivers (possibly for hp?) while the install was going on and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried another thumbdrive.  It sounds silly, but I've had weirdness with some thumbdrive/computer combinations.

Comment: @Matt: Ubuntu has the USB 3.0 drivers already, so I'm not quite convinced that they are being honest.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer have an SD slot card, install from it. Put the image in both, the CD and the SD card. Your computer will start from the CD and it will load the installation from the SD. This is because your SD has USB 2.0 ports.

The HP Envy 15 have more issues to solve. You can find how to solve them in my blog:

http://airamrguez.blogspot.com/search/label/HP%20Envy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edit grub file:

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Add the line:

```
pci=nomsi
```

Then save and exit (type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then type <kbd>Y</kbd> then type <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

Then execute:

```
sudo nano update-grub
```

Reboot and USB 3.0 should be working, like mounting PENs, etc.