# What is the state of the Ubuntu USB 3.0 driver

Tags: usb

I have a device, that over USB 3.0 enumerates as a speaker and a microphone (two interfaces, each with a single endpoint) under Windows 7.

However, under Ubuntu 13.04, only the speaker shows up. How do I determine if the problem is in the AudioClass driver, USB 3.0 driver or the device?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/12139/does-ubuntu-support-usb-3-0

Comment: Thanks, @Mitch. In my case, devices that represent themselves as only one thing work fine, but this speaker and mic does not.

Comment: 13.04... 
Is it possible with that machine to upgrade to 14.04?

Comment: @Akiva, I will try that. The timeframe of the question got a little long. Therefore, a good answer would indicate a minimal version of Ubuntu, under which the above device is supported. The device implements USB Audio Class 1.